# Append Field value with another field

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to have a MS SQL database field that has the value of another field in the same record appended to it.

To give it come context the dynamic field will contain an API call where I need to include the record ID. I would like the value the API field to be identical for each record and and use a reference to the ID field when when you query the table the API field contains the result of the API call.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Kevin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create calculated columns:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD
    [columnName] AS ('YourStaticString' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), IdColumn))
```

Comment: Thanks, That sort of worked however it has defined the column as an int so when I run a select statement I get an error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'MYSTRING' to data type int. How do I set the column to varchar(200)?

Comment: CAST or CONVERT it to string: `CAST(IdColumn AS VARCHAR(200))` or `CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), IdColumn)`. Also please note that the calculated columns can not be altered, you have to drop and recreate it if you want to modify the calculation.

Comment: I have posted a different but related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515320/show-image-in-asp-view

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use ASP.NET, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the table design, you can create a view of the table which has the additional field in it.

```
 CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
 AS
      SELECT *, 'SomeText' + IdColumn AS DynamicColumn
        FROM MyTable
```

*Note it is better to specify the columns explicitly, whereas I've used `SELECT *` for brevity.*