# Show Image in asp view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

I have an image tag in a database field which I want to show the image in the index and detail views within an MVC project. Currently the both pages just show the text

The view code for that field is:

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QRCode)
    </td>
```

How to to code the view pages to show the image the link points to rather than the link text?

Cheers,
Kevin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link : [displaying image from db in Razor/MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149430/displaying-image-from-db-in-razor-mvc3)
Two possibilities.

Write a controller action instead which given an image id will return this image:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
{
    byte[] image = ... go and fetch the image buffer from the database given the id
    return File(image, "image/jpg");
}
```

and then:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "SomeController", new { id = item.Id })" alt="@item.CountryName" />
```

Obviously now in your initial model you don't need the Image property. This will be retrieved subsequently in the controller action responsible for that.

Another possibility is to use data URI scheme to embed the images as base64 strings but it might not be widely supported by all browsers:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image))" alt="@item.CountryName" />
```

You don't need a controller action in this case as the images are directly embedded into your markup as base64 strings.

Happy Coding..!!

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go. currently the field contains the following: <img src=http://qr4.nl/Gen.aspx?key=testkey&type=text&cont=https://dev-amscan.azurewebsites.net/Asset/Details/1 /> so would I need to remove the tag code?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained the link is an API call which returns a png

Comment: I used the following in the index view:        <td>
            <img src="@Url.Content(item.QRCode)" alt="Image" />
        </td>

Comment: if you are storing Image path than you can even use <img src="@Model.ImageUrl" alt="" /> . This will display your image on view.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for the index view:

```
    <td>
        <img src="@Url.Content(item.QRCode)" alt="Image" />
    </td>
```

Thanks for the help.

The problem I now have is getting the image to show in the details page. The code I have tried is:

```
    <dd>
        <img src=@Model.QRCode alt="" />
    </dd>
```

The other columns that work on the details page use:

```
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TestingFrequency)
    </dd>
```

But I have tried many combinations of code and I can't seem to get it to work.

Any further tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Cracked it! as simple as: <img src="@Model.QRCode" alt="" /> The error was due to a few lines down.